# SQL query from a table

Tags: mysql, sql

For my CIS class, I have SQL project, I'm still very new to SQL and trying to learn it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Query: Write a query to show the total value of all the orders that customers living in San Jose or Turlock have placed.

This is what I tried and giving me an error:

```
select SUM(price * quantity) as Revenue
FROM customer,salesorder
where customer.cno = salesorder.cno AND
        zip = 95124 AND zip = 95380
        AND zip = 95382
```

The error I'm getting is: #1054 - Unknown column 'price' in 'field list'

Table: [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyAFl.jpg)

Database codes:

```
create table zipcode (
  zip   integer(5) primary key,
  city  varchar(30),
  State varchar(20));


create table employee (
  eno       varchar(10) primary key,
  ename     varchar(30),
  zip       integer(5) references zipcode(zip),
  hire_date date);



create table book (
  bno       integer(5) primary key,
  bname     varchar(30),
  qoh       integer(5) not null,
  price     dec(6,2) not null);


create table customer (
  cno       integer(5) primary key,
  cname     varchar(30),
  street    varchar(30),
  zip       integer(5)  references zipcode(zip),
  phone     char(12));



create table salesOrder (
  ono       integer(5)  primary key,
  cno       integer(5)  references customer(cno),
  eno       varchar(10)  references employees(Eno),
  received  date,
  shipped   date
);



create table orderLine (
  ono       integer(5)  references salesOrder(ono),
  bno       integer(5)  references book(bno),
  quantity  integer(10) not null,
  primary key (ono, bno));




insert into zipcode values (98225, 'Bellingham', 'WA');
insert into zipcode values (95388, 'Winton', 'CA');
insert into zipcode values (44242, 'Stow', 'OH');
insert into zipcode values (61536, 'Hanna city', 'IL');
insert into zipcode values (01254, 'Richmond', 'MA');
insert into zipcode values (95124, 'San Jose', 'CA');
insert into zipcode values (95382, 'Turlock', 'CA');
insert into zipcode values (95380, 'Turlock', 'CA');
insert into zipcode values (98102, 'Seattle', 'WA');



insert into employee values ('P0239401', 'Jones Hoffer',98225, '2000-12-12');
insert into employee values ('P0239402', 'Jeffrey Prescott',95388, '2016-11-07');
insert into employee values ('P0239403', 'Fred NcFaddeb',95124, '2008-09-01');
insert into employee values ('P0239404', 'Karen Ives',98102, '2014-05-21');


insert into book values (10501, 'Forensic Accounting',200, 229.99);
insert into book values (10502, 'SAP Business One',159, 149.99);
insert into book values (10503, 'Fraud Cases',190, 179.99);
insert into book values (10504, 'CPA Review',65, 279.99);
insert into book values (10605, 'Quickbooks for Business',322, 59.99);
insert into book values (10704, 'Financial Accounting',129, 164.99);
insert into book values (10879, 'Managerial Accounting',155, 114.99);
insert into book values (10933, 'Cost Accounting',122, 219.99);
insert into book values (10948, 'Intermediate Accounting',123, 164.99);
insert into book values (10965, 'Accounting Information Systems',211, 259.99);
insert into book values (10988, 'XBRL in Nutshell',124, 109.99);


insert into customer values (23511, 'Michelle Kuan', '123 Main St.',98225, '360-636-5555');
insert into customer values (23512, 'George Myer', '237 Ash Ave.',95124, '312-678-5555');
insert into customer values (23513, 'Richard Gold', '111 Inwood St.',95124, '312-883-7337');
insert into customer values (23514, 'Robert Smith', '54 Gate Dr.',95388, '206-832-1221');
insert into customer values (23515, 'Christopher David', '777 Loto St.',98225, '360-458-9878');
insert into customer values (23516, 'Adam Beethoven', '234 Park Rd.',95380, '209-546-7299');
insert into customer values (23517, 'Ludwig Bach', '5790 Walnut St.',95382, '209-638-2712');
insert into customer values (23518, 'Kathleen Pedersen', '1233 Federal Ave E', 98102, '360-573-7239');


insert into salesOrder values (1020, 23511, 'P0239403', '2018-01-13', '2018-01-15');
insert into salesOrder values (1021, 23513, 'P0239401', '2018-01-13', '2018-01-16');
insert into salesOrder values (1022, 23513, 'P0239402', '2018-01-15', '2018-01-17');
insert into salesOrder values (1023, 23512, 'P0239403', '2018-01-16', '2018-01-18');
insert into salesOrder values (1024, 23511, 'P0239402', '2018-01-18', '2018-01-20');
insert into salesOrder values (1025, 23511, 'P0239403', '2018-01-29', '2017-01-31');
insert into salesOrder values (1026, 23512, 'P0239404', '2018-01-30', '2018-01-31');
insert into salesOrder values (1027, 23512, 'P0239402', '2018-01-30', '2018-01-31');
insert into salesOrder values (1028, 23512, 'P0239404', '2018-01-30', '2018-01-31');
insert into salesOrder (ONO, CNO, ENO, RECEIVED) values (1029, 23513, 'P0239402', '2018-01-31');
insert into salesOrder (ONO, CNO, ENO, RECEIVED) values (1030, 23511, 'P0239401', '2018-01-31');



insert into orderLine values (1020, 10501,7);
insert into orderLine values (1020, 10502,15);
insert into orderLine values (1020, 10504,3);
insert into orderLine values (1020, 10503,6);
insert into orderLine values (1021, 10605,4);
insert into orderLine values (1022, 10605,2);
insert into orderLine values (1022, 10704,4);
insert into orderLine values (1023, 10879,4);
insert into orderLine values (1023, 10988,19);
insert into orderLine values (1024, 10502,7);
insert into orderLine values (1024, 10988,2);
insert into orderLine values (1025, 10502,4);
insert into orderLine values (1025, 10988,3);
insert into orderLine values (1025, 10948,2);
insert into orderLine values (1026, 10965,15);
insert into orderLine values (1026, 10933,5);
insert into orderLine values (1027, 10933,21);
insert into orderLine values (1028, 10933,9);
insert into orderLine values (1028, 10965,11);
insert into orderLine values (1029, 10933,4);
insert into orderLine values (1029, 10965,10);
insert into orderLine values (1029, 10988,3);
insert into orderLine values (1030, 10965,6);
```

Comment: There isn't `price` column in `customer` or `salesorder`

Comment: update yoru question and and add the related  table schema

Comment: You should check (better still: post here) your table definitions, to see the real names of the columns thtat you call `price` and `quantity`. Also (unrelated to this error), some of your `AND`s should really be `OR`s.

Comment: And adding to what @Dario said "SQL query from a table" is very broad scoped. You should be naming your question titles in such a way that people here could easily understand and want to help you right away rather than going through the entire post and then realize it is not their line of expertise.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm still very new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The error I'm getting is: #1054 - Unknown column 'price' in 'field list'`

As per your query you have not added the table having price column.
If you can see your DDL statements price column is in book table and you have to join this table to get the required result.
I guess this should work

```
SELECT  SUM(book.price*orderline.quantity) AS "order value" from customer 
JOIN salesorder
ON salesorder.cno=customer.cno 
JOIN orderline
ON salesorder.ono=orderline.ono
JOIN book
ON orderline.bno=book.bno 
JOIN zipcode
ON customer.zip = zipcode.zip
WHERE city in ('Turlock', 'San Jose')
```

Comment: Getting an error. I don't know what I'm really doing wrong. #1054 - Unknown column 'price' in 'field list'

Comment: please mark it as answer and vote up if u are satisfied with the answer. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

That no make sense on

```
AND zip = 95124 
AND zip = 95380
AND zip = 95382
```

I guess you want to use `IN`

From your table schema join `Orderline` and `Book` you will get  `price` and `quantity`

```
select SUM(b.price * o.quantity) 
FROM customer c 
INNER JOIN salesorder s ON c.cno = s.cno
INNER JOIN Orderline o ON s.ono = o.ono
INNER JOIN Book b ON b.bno = o.bno
where zip IN (95124,95380,95382);
```

*sqlfiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/07a9c0b/8*

Answer (score 1):

Once check the table where the column price exists in...I see it in the table book
and yet you did not use the table book in your query... so this is how you should do it..

```
select SUM(Book.price * Orderline.quantity) 
FROM customer 
INNER JOIN salesorder  ON customer.cno = salesorder.cno
INNER JOIN Orderline  ON salesorder.ono = Orderline.ono
INNER JOIN Book  ON Book.bno = Orderline.bno
where customer.zip IN (95124,95380,95382);
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I missed that!

Answer (score 0):

First thing that needs correction is an aggregate function like sum, avg etc need a group clause as well. For example

**select sum(price * quantity) as revenue from customers c, salesorder s  where 
c.customer_no=s.customer_no group by c.customer_no**

It will return the total revenue a single customer generated . Second thing is
for filtering based on several Zip Code you  can use IN clause like

where zip_no in ('A','B','C')

Third please check you are writing correct column name  and spelling of column as well of price